# Configure port range mapping into containers.yaml for google container engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I followed all the google documentation to deploy a docker image into goole compute ([this one](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/container_vms?hl=fr#creating_containers_at_time_of_instance_creation)) but I can't find more informations about google-container-manifest options.

For example I can't add a port range.
I tried that without success :

```
  ports:
    - containerPort: 80
      hostPort: 80
    - containerPort: 443
      hostPort: 443
    - containerPort: "10000-20000"
      hostPort: "10000-20000"
```

Where can we find all parameters we can use for google container manifest ?
And is it possible to add a port range mapping ?

Thx

[Edit with @alex solution]

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  hostNetwork: true
  containers:
    - name: test1
      image: eu.gcr.io/app-1234/image
      imagePullPolicy: Always
```

And now all port on docker container are expose on google VM.

Do not forget to configure a network to expose all port you need like that :

```
gcloud compute networks create test-network

gcloud compute firewall-rules create test-allow-http --allow tcp:80 --network test-network
gcloud compute firewall-rules create test-allow-ssh --allow tcp:22 --network test-network
gcloud compute firewall-rules create test-allow-https --allow tcp:443 --network test-network
gcloud compute firewall-rules create test-allow-video --allow udp:10000-20000,icmp --network test-network
```

And run instance like that :

```
gcloud compute instances create test-example \
    --image container-vm \
    --metadata-from-file google-container-manifest=containers.yaml \
    --zone europe-west1-b \
    --machine-type n1-standard-2 \
    --network test-network
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned a little lower down on that docs page:

> Documentation for the container manifest can be found in the
>   [Kubernetes API Pod Specification](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/api-reference/v1/definitions.html#_v1_pod). The container VM is running a
>   simple Kubelet and not the entire Kubernetes control plane, so the
>   `v1.PodSpec` honored by the container VM is limited to `containers`,
>   `volumes`, and `restartPolicy`.

Regarding adding such a large range of ports, though, would you mind explaining your use case? Currently the API does not support arbitrary port ranges, only lists of explicit ports. If what you really want is for all the ports on the machine to be usable by your container, you might want to consider the `hostNetwork` option in the `v1.PodSpec`, which will run your container directly on the host's network with no need for port mapping.

Comment: Thx Alex, I missed this link :/ I need a large range port for a videobridge server. But Docker have trouble with large range :( [bug repport](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/11185). For the moment I just add 4 port one by one and google change that into a docker range port :) "0.0.0.0:10000-10003->10000-10003/udp". I will try hostNetwork !